# Disable dumping of entire data model when error occurs in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I want to turn off dumping out the contents of the entire data model when an error occurs but I want to still display debug() messages. Setting the debug mode to 0 turns off everything.

I guess one option is to set the debug mode to 0 and use something like echo statements but I was hoping that there was a targeted command for disabling just the data model dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`debug()` is a special CakePHP function specifically to dump a data model.  If you only want part of the model, debug just that part.  For example, you don't have to do `debug( $this );`, you can do `debug( $this->params );`

Other than that, you can use `var_dump` or `print_r` or `echo`...

If you're talking about the debug messages that happen on warnings and errors, try setting debug mode to 1.

From the comments in [the core.php config file](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3/app/config/core.php):

> Production Mode:
>       0: No error messages, errors, or warnings shown. Flash messages redirect.
>
> Development Mode:
>       1: Errors and warnings shown, model caches refreshed, flash messages halted.
>       2: As in 1, but also with full debug messages and SQL output.

Comment: It dumps out the data model (and a stack trace) on an error even if I have no debug() statements in the code.

Comment: Yes, it happens on an error. It dumps out the fill model on anything above level 0. I'll just go with one of the alternative methods.